# jquery css to a class in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this to set font colour of `.pic` which is inside of `#wrapper`

```
$("#wrapper .pic").css(color, "#F00");
```

How do I set the colours to 2 divs with same class?

```
<div id="wrapper"><div class="pic">TEST 1</div></div>
<div id="wrapperInner"><div class="pic">TEST 2</div></div>
```

Comment: Why not just `$(".pic").css("color", "#F00");`

Comment: `$(".pic").css(color, "#F00");` or `$("#wrapper .pic, #wrapperInner .pic").css(color, "#F00");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can modify the css of one or more elements by separating the selectors with a comma:

```
$("#wrapper .pic, #wrapperInner .pic").css("color", "#F00");
```

* "color" should be in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

`$('div.pic').css('color', '#F00');`

Comment: This only matches divs that have the class `.pic`.  His current code would be any elements inside an element with `#wrapper` that are class `.pic`

Comment: I interpreted the question quite literally and based on the code that immediately followed the question: _"How do I set the colours to 2 divs with same class?"_ Thus I specified `div.pic` in the selector. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
$('div > .pic').css('color','#f00');
```

Comment: This one will only match `.pic` elements that are direct descendants of a `div`